# PowerShell Graph Group Update permissions

Tags: powershell, office365

I am using the following code to bulk update some groups in my domain:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.ReadWrite.All, User.ReadWrite.All, GroupMember.ReadWrite.All

foreach($_ in $HR){
  New-MgGroupMember -GroupID $Group.Id -DirectoryObjectID $_.Id
}
```

but I Keep getting an error message about insufficient permissions. Everything I can find online says the Group and User permissions in the scope should cover that cmdlet. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to define `$Group`. FWIW using `$_` as the iterator variable in a `foreach` loop statement is also a bit of an antipattern, as it easily causes confusion with `ForEach-Object` (which behaves slightly different than the loop construct)

Comment: I defined Group and HR just Omitted them due to Privacy Stuffs. Tried Updating the Variable and will remember that going forward but it did not resolve the Permissions issue.

Comment: assuming `$Group.Id` is the group's GUID and `$_.ID` are user's GUIDs and not other object types then there is no issue with your code. Try a direct API call and see if you get the same error: `Invoke-MgRestMethod POST 'v1.0/groups/xxx-xxxx-xxxx/members/$ref' -Body @{ '@odata.id' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyy' }` where `xxx-xxxx-xxxx` is the Group's GUID and `yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyy` is a user's GUID